# Can AMP script tags be placed into a single file?

Tags: amp-html

That is, if there's a way to put all the AMP component script tags into one file, so they can better manage those tags in a batch with meaningful names.

Meaning, instead of having

```js
<script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
```

on the page, can these tags be put into one single JS file (e.g. amp_components_for_product_page.js) to make the code cleaner?

There seems no straightforward way to do this (JS in JS) even on normal webpages, but still wonder if someone knows the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible; the AMP won't validate.
Consider using a server-side templating system for this.
    E.g.

```js
<?php include "amp_components_for_product_page.php"; ?>
```